# How to prevent one element from pushing another element - reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search box for my table below it. Now, when I start searching, the dropdown from the search box keeps pushing the table below to the bottom.

I have tried using z-index on the search box but that wouldn't do the trick. How can I solve this issue

```
const styles = {
 zIndex:1000
}

 <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6">
              <div  className="form-group">
              <FormGroup>
              <Label for="className">Select items</Label>   
               <ReactSearchBox  style={styles}
               placeholder="Placeholder"
               value="Doe"
               data={test}
               callback={record => console.log('records',record)}
      />


 <RctCardContent>
         <div>
          <Table style={tableStyle} hover responsive className="mb-0">
          </Table>
         </div>
</RctCardContent>
```

Comment: Using a z-index doesn't do anything, unless you take it out of the document/layout flow: e.g. by using `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information that you have given , apply position: relative to the ReactSearchBox  since that it will keep it in the the flow of the document and hence your higher z-index will place it on top of all the elements which have lower z-index.Try fiddling with top,bottom,left,right properties on it to place it correctly.